# Linux 'find' only for current folder and specified ones

Tags: linux, recursion, command-line, find, filesystems

I need to find files in the current folder (non-recursively) and some other folders (recursively). For example I have a tree structure like:

- folder1/
- folder2/

  - folder2-1/

    - file2-1.php
- folder3/

  - file3-1.php
- file1.php
- file2.php

I want to find files `file1.php`, `file2.php` and `file2-1.php` only. So, search in the root + folder2/ recursively.

All the resources I could find describe either

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.php" // gives `file1.php` and `file2.php`
```

or

```
find folder2 -iname "*.php" // gives me `file2-1.php`
```

So:

**Q.** How do I combine these commands?

P.S. I should be able to send the list of the found files further in the command line as well (for example to xgettext).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this?

```
( find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.php"; find folder2 -iname "*.php") | xgettext
```

Comment: added `-maxdepth 1 ` for only current folde did the job, thanks